# Allow user input during javascript loop and make it work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm trying to program a music play button with the following features:

Click once to play the track
A second click while the track is playing will fade it out
A third click while the track is fading will stop the track.

I implemented the fade with a loop that decreases the volume.  I have two problems.  First, it appears that during the time the volume-reduction loop is executing, user clicks are ignored, so my third feature is not working.  The second problem is that while my implementation works quite well in Firefox, in Chrome, there is no fade, the music simply drops to 0 volume.

```
<script>
    var status = 'S' ;
    function pausecomp(ms) {
        ms += new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date() < ms){}
    }

    function play_it( aud_id ) {
        if ( status == 'S' ) {
            var offset = $("#"+aud_id+"_offset")[0].value ;
            if ( offset > $("#" + aud_id )[0].duration ) { alert ( "offset beyond end of track" ); return; }
            $("#" + aud_id)[0].currentTime = offset ;
            $("#" + aud_id)[0].volume = 1 ;
            $("#" + aud_id)[0].play() ;
            status = 'P' ;
            $("#"+aud_id+"_div").css('backgroundColor', 'cyan') ;
        } else if ( status == 'P' ) {
            $("#"+aud_id+"_div").css('backgroundColor', 'green') ;
            status = 'F' ;
            fadeout( aud_id ) ;
            stop( aud_id );
            status = 'S' ;
        } else if ( status == 'F' ) {
            stop( aud_id ) ;
            status = 'S' ;
        }
    }

    function fadeout(aud_id) {
    // reduce the volume by .01 every 60 ms
        var volume = $("#" + aud_id)[0].volume ;
        var stop = 100 ;
        if ( volume > 0 ) {
            stop = Math.floor( 100*volume ) ;
        }
        for ( var i = 1 ; i < stop ; i++ ) {
            reduceVol($("#" + aud_id)[0]);
            pausecomp(60) ;
        }
        $("#" + aud_id)[0].volume = 0 ;
    }

    function reduceVol(audio_obj) {
        var volume = audio_obj.volume ;
        volume = volume - 0.01 ;
        if ( volume >= 0 ) {
            audio_obj.volume = volume ;
        }
    }

    function stop(aud_id) {
        $("#" + aud_id)[0].pause() ;
    }
</script>

<div style='display:inline-block; width:300px;'>
    <h3><% $events[$i] || '' %></h3>
    <audio id="my_audio_<% $i %>">
        <source src="<% $src %>mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <input type='hidden' id='my_audio_<% $i %>_offset' value='<% $offset %>' />
    <div id='my_audio_<% $i %>_div' onclick="play_it('my_audio_<% $i %>')"><% join '<br/>' , ($title,$artist,$album)  %></div>
    <button type="button" style='width:200px;' onclick="stop('my_audio_<% $i %>')">Stop</button>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to implement the fade that will continue to allow user-input so the click to stop immediately works?  Also, how can I make this work as expected in Chrome?

Comment: pausecomp is deadlocking the page. Do not use a for loop, use a setTimeout to do the looping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem - as you've found out yourself - is the loop. Browsers first evaluate a loop completely until any further user input is processed. You will therefore have to get rid of the loop which will require some pseudo-parallelized prozessing.

To make your life easier, you might want to have a look into [jQuery's `animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. This function is intended to only animate CSS properties... but using the `step` argument you can also modify non-CSS properties like volume.

A rough sketch would look something like this:

```
$({volume: 0}).animate({volume: 100}, {
    step: function(volume) {
        audio_obj.volume = volume;
    }
})
```

Obviously you'll have to play with the arguments to `animate` a bit to get the timing right.